# Why all the elements in my list have got the same time of creation?

Tags: c++, time.h

I wanted to add to nodes in my list variable, that contains time elapsed from start of program. Unfortunatly, all of them has got the same. What is wrong in my code?

```
    void MyList:: pushBack(val nval)
{
    if (size == 0)
    {
        first->elem = nval;
        first->time = ((clock() / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)) * 1000);
        size++;
        return;
    }
    Node *n = new Node(); 
    n->time= ((clock() / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)) *1000);
    n->elem = nval;
    last->next = n;
    last = n;
    size++;
//  delete n;

}
   struct Node {
    double time;
    val elem;
    Node *next=nullptr;
};

class MyList
{
    int size = 0;
    Node* first;
    Node* last = first;
MyList();
void pushBack(val nval);
~MyList();
};
```

Comment: Maybe what is wrong is that your computer is exteremly fast **or --->** you are just asking for someone to debug it for you

Comment: Please edit question and add the code that adds elements.

Comment: Depending on your platform, `clock()` probably returns CPU time and not actual time. Also, its resolution is pretty low.

Comment: Rerun the test with 100 thousand Nodes.

Comment: What if you use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why all the elements in my list have got the same time of creation?

You are using

```
((clock() / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)) * 1000);
```

to get the value for the `time` member variable. That is time in milliseconds. Today's computers can do a lot of work in a millisecond. The time taken to create all the objects appears to be less than a millisecond. That's why you see the same value of `time` for all your objects.

If the resolution of `clock` is greater than a millisecond, you will see the same value of `time` for larger number of objects.

Comment: That's a plausible explanation.

Comment: The actual resolution of `clock` is probably even worse than a millisecond.